# I get an error when I am try using -ls with different directory. And I don't know why

Tags: bash, ls

I am using `-ls` to check if my files exist. The problem is when I run this:

```
infile=/Volumes/malrosie/data/satellite/chlor_a/cmems/mapped/4km/daily/*.nc
```

```
ls -l $infile | tail -n 1
```

I get what I want:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 malrosie  staff   91748221 Nov 12  2021 /Volumes/malrosie/data/satellite/chlor_a/cmems/mapped/4km/daily/20210630_d-ACRI-L4-CHL-MULTI_4KM-GLO-REP.nc
```

But when I run the same command on a different directory:

```
infile1=/Volumes/malrosie/data/satellite/chlor_a/cmems/mapped/4km/daily_crop/*.nc
```

```
ls -l $infile1 | tail -n 1
```

I get an error:

```
bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

Why is this? How do I solve it?

Comment: This is normal: There's a limit to the combined size of environment variables and command-line arguments.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What does that mean?

Comment: ...it means that only so many characters worth of filenames can fit on a command line, and that environment variables also count against that limit? I don't know what part of the statement didn't make sense to you the way I originally explained it, so I don't know how to rephrase it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok got it!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy but why does it work for the other directory?

Comment: Because the other directory isn't so large as to trigger the problem. It's the combined length of the file names that's the issue.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I’m sorry, if my questions are dumb, I’m just trying to understand the issue. But the other directory has the same number of files, larger in size even.

Comment: It's not the size of the files' contents, it's the length of their combined names, _including_ in this case the (rather long) directory name.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok. That explains it! Thank you so much for taking your time to explain this to me.

Comment: Compare output of `printf '%s\0' /Volumes/malrosie/data/satellite/chlor_a/cmems/mapped/4km/daily/*.nc | wc -c` to the output you get with the other relevant path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is longer than can fit on an command line.

---

#### Making The `ls` Run Anyhow

```
files=( /Volumes/malrosie/data/satellite/chlor_a/cmems/mapped/4km/daily/*.nc )
printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" | xargs -0 ls -l | tail -n 1
```

Because `printf` is built into the shell, it isn't subject to limits on the maximum number of characters that can be on a command line. We're then feeding the output of `printf` into `xargs`, which is responsible for starting `ls -l` as many times as necessary to get through the filenames on its stdin.

Because of the `tail -n 1`, all but the last copy of `ls` will have its results thrown away, making the existence of the other copies pointless.

---

#### If `ls` isn't actually important to you

You don't need `tail` to check if your files exist, and using it unnecessarily is slow: If *even one* file exists, your glob expression succeeded. Thus, a fast and terse approach is:

```
files=( /Volumes/malrosie/data/satellite/chlor_a/cmems/mapped/4km/daily/*.nc )
if (( ${#files[@]} > 1 )); then
  echo "Great: ${#files[@]} files exist" >&2
elif (( ${#files[@]} == 1 )); then
  if [[ -L ${files[0]} || -e ${files[0]} ]]; then
    echo "One file exists, ${files[0]}" >&2
  else
    echo "No files exist" >&2
  fi
else
  echo "No files exist, and nullglob is enabled" >&2
fi
```

Here, we're assigning the results of the glob to an array named `files`, after which we can refer to `${#files[@]}` to get the number of files named in the array (which may be 1 even if there are no entries due to default globbing behavior).

Thus:

- If the number of array entries is more than one, there definitely do exist matching files.
- If the number of array entries is exactly one, it may contain a glob expression (`.../*.nc`) instead of a file, so we need to check whether the first entry (the one at index 0) either exists, or is a symlink (in which case the existence check can say false if the link itself exists but points to a location where nothing exists).
- If the number of array entries is zero, it definitely contains no files.